# Check if managed identity is configured from .NET Core application

Tags: .net, azure, azure-managed-identity

I want to know if application has managed identity configured(let's say App Service, but really does not matter). So far I see next options:

- Manually check if some environment variable defined, for example:
  IDENTITY_ENDPOINT
- Add flag to config, which I will set during
  deployment to specify if MI is configured or not
- If I connecting to
  Azure SQL, check if connection string has no User ID specified

All those seems to work for me, but I am wondering if something built-in `Azure.Identity` SDK exists.

Answer (score 1):

The package `Azure.Identity` just provides some credentials to do Azure AD auth and require AD token to access resource projected by Azure AD. We cannot use it to check if Azure resource has enabled MSI. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet).

Regarding the issue, I suggest you use Azure rest API to get the resource then check if the property `identity` has value.